# Find unique pairs from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list consisting of numbers, I want to find the **unique** pairs from the list, such that:

> 1. x>y
> 2. There is no element in the sequence between x and y.

x is the first element of the pair and y the second.

My logic is to:

> Iterate over the list : i
>
> Iterate over the list again : j (Nested loop)
>
> Iterate from i to j+1 : k
>
> check if k is in the list
>
> If k is in the list -> pass else print(list[i],list[j])

My Code:

```
l=[15,10,1,8,5,1] 
l=sorted(l,reverse=True)
print(l)
res=[]

for i in range(len(l)):
  for j in range(len(l)):
    for k in range(l[j],l[i]+1):
      if k in l:
        #pass
        #print(l[i],l[j+1])
        #continue
        continue
      else:
        res.append((l[i],l[j]))
        #print(k)
        break


print(res)
```

> Expected Output: [(15,10),(10,8),(8,5),(5,1)]
>
> My Output : [(15, 10), (15, 8), (15, 5), (15, 1), (15, 1),
>    (10, 8), 
>   (10, 5), (10, 1), (10, 1), (8, 5),
>
> (8, 1), (8, 1), (5, 1), (5, 1)]

My Code doesnt workout as expected at all. Maybe the logic is wrong

Comment: Please [edit] to post your current attempt, with a description of the current output, the expected output, and any errors you get. That's what Stack Overflow is for, solving specific problems with your code, not to do the work for you.

Comment: I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple and you were very close when you sorted the data. You need just one iteration to go over the data. The condition is to check if we are not hitting the end and x > y.

```
l=[15,10,1,8,5,1] 
l=sorted(l,reverse=True)
print(l)
res=[]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i+1 < len(l) and l[i] > l[i+1]:
        res.append((l[i],l[i+1]))
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Could you please explain why we check whethere we are hitting the end or not?

Comment: so that you do not hit the out of range.When i = len(l) you should stop instead of trying to append l[i+1] that does not exist.  Another way to handle is run the loop to range(len(l)) -1 than you don't need the check.